# Is it possible to send other things to the event logger then system info?

Tags: c#, zabbix

I have been trying for the past few days, unsuccessfully, to send some sort of event log to zabbix. And I know there are other options but for my project, I need severity, which is, from my understanding only available in event logger. I have tried everything so I started to wonder, is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse

- Windows Event Log with [eventlog[]](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent/win_keys)
- text files with [log[] or logrt[]](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items)